Crawlee Python: How add custom cookies to a request
What is the right way to add custom cookies (key-value pairs) to a request executed via Crawlee?
Lets say website requires custom-cookie for auth purposes (cookie sid=1234), how to add this cookie to all subsequent requests to in this example category-pages (not include in all requests, but to this category-destination).
There is something like a session, and a session-pool, but how to reach these objects?
In the documentation there it describes max_pool_size of session-pool has default size of 1000, should one then iterate through all the sessions in the session-pool and set for each session the session-id to the session.cookies (dict)?
If yes, how to reach these objects?
Imagine the below from the tutorial, default handler handles the incoming request, it wants to enqueue requests to the category-pages. Lets say these category-pages require this sid-cookie to be set, how to achieve this?
file: main.py
async def main() -> None:
    
    crawler = PlaywrightCrawler(
        
        # Let's limit our crawls to make our tests shorter and safer.
        max_requests_per_crawl=50,
        # Provide our router instance to the crawler.
        request_handler=router,
        headless=False
    )
    
    # start crawler based on default request-queue
    await crawler.run(['https://warehouse-theme-metal.myshopify.com/collections'])

file: routes.py
@router.default_handler
async def default_handler(context: PlaywrightCrawlingContext) -> None:
    # This is a fallback route which will handle the start URL.
    context.log.info(f'default_handler is processing {context.request.url}')
    
    await context.page.wait_for_selector('.collection-block-item')

    await context.enqueue_links(
        selector='.collection-block-item',
        label='CATEGORY',
    )

Looked in the documentation, checked Google, Stackoverflow, code examples, nothing on this topic.
